# Certificate in iPhone App

Tags: iphone, xcode, certificate

I'm working with iPhone application and i want put it in my iPhone.
In xcode there is a overview "device - 3.1.3 | debug" but when i "build and go" the project there is an certificate error.

I have download a certificate "mobileprovision" with a correct "Identifier" but i don't know how put it in my xcode project.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to have a subscription with apple to develop iPhone applications. I assume you do. That said, once you generate a certificate (through key chain) and upload it to the apple developers site, you can generate a provisioning profile and input the identifier of your iPhone: download that provisioning profile and installing it is as easy as dragging it to xcode. If everything matches, you can select device and build and go and it will download to your device

Answer (score 0):

After downloading your provisioning profile on your mac, you first install it. Then check your installed profile in : admin/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles folder. If it exists, it automatically attached to your xcode project. Open XCode> Window > Organizer > On left-side of Organizer, select "Provisioning Profiles" tab. There, you can find list of profiles you have.